# Undefined index error captcha

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me with Undefined index: captcha error.
The error says 'captcha' is undefined with the following code:-

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['captcha']) || (strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha']) != strtolower($_SESSION['captcha'])))   {
```

Kindly assist.

Comment: One of those array indices is undefined - does the error tell you which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defined in $_REQUEST but not in $_SESSION probably.

Comment: Ok thanks, if what i am thinking right now would be the solution. You deserve an applause.

Comment: Errors rarely lie. If they say it's undefined, whatever you think about what was done or not, it's undefined. Just believe what errors say.